# Flask Api route works with resquests.post(json=dict)

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I have a flask login route that is supposed to return an access token

My Route looks like,

```
auth_api = Api(auth_bp)
parser = auth_api.parser()
auth = auth_api.model('Auth', {
    'email': fields.String(required=True, description='Email'),
    'password': fields.String(required=True, description='Password'),
})
parser.add_argument('email', type=str, required=True, help='Email', location='form')
parser.add_argument('password', type=str, required=True, help='Password', location='form')

class LoginApi(Resource):
    @auth_api.marshal_with(auth, code=201)
    def post(self):
        req = parser.parse_args()
        print(req)
        email = req.get('email', None)
        print(f"Email: {email}")
        password = req.get('password', None)
        print(f"Password: {password}")
        user = guard.authenticate(email, password)
        print(user)
        access_token = {'access_token': guard.encode_jwt_token(user)}
        print(access_token)
        return access_token, 201
```

Currently, in a separate terminal when I run a `requests.post()` it just returns, `{'email': None, 'password': None}` and not the access_token.  I can see the `access_token` in my logs of my flask app so it creates that variable.

My request looks like,

```
creds = requests.post(
    login_url,
    data={'email': 'wally@starlabs.com', 'password': 'west'}
).json()
In [2]: creds
Out[2]: {'email': None, 'password': None}
```

What am I missing?

**Update:**
If I change my `LoginApi` to,

```
class LoginApi(Resource):
    def post(self):
        req = request.get_json(force=True)
        email = req.get('email', None)
        password = req.get('password', None)
        user = guard.authenticate(email, password)
        access_token = {'access_token': guard.encode_jwt_token(user)}
        return access_token
```

I can run,

```
creds = requests.post(
    login_url,
    json={'email': 'wally@starlabs.com', 'password': 'west'}
).json()
In [4]: creds
Out[4]: {'access_token': 'a-jwt-string'}
```

But if I run `requests.post` with `data` instead,

```
creds = requests.post(
    login_url,
    data={'email': 'wally@starlabs.com', 'password': 'west'}
).json()
```

I get `Out[6]: {'message': 'Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'}`

I get the same error if I run, `curl http://localhost:5000/api/login -X POST -d '{"email":"wally@starlabs.com","password":"west"}'`

Comment: Its difficult to replicate, but maybe you could try return  json.dumps(access_token)

Comment: I could link the repo?

Comment: Use jsonify(response)

Comment: https://github.com/spitfiredd/flask-vue-login all the flask related stuff is in the `backend` folder.